# Can we use Jade Template/Js for developing Firefox Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, pug, firefox-addon-sdk

I am trying to develop a Firefox Extension to have the same functionality as of existing Chrome Plugin.
For Chrome we are using Jade templates. I want to know whether Firefox Extension development supports Jade too. It seems the Panel uses different techniques to load JS etc. Not sure if it can use the Templates also

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this? Did you get an error? Please provide more info.

If you're using the add-on sdk ( you mention Panel ) then the contents of the panel should work just like any other web page. For best results, you'll need to load all of your html, js, css and templates from the data directory in your add-on. When you load those assets you can use relative paths, eg

```
<script src="some-file.js">
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... after drilling down a bit more I found that,for the Chrome we are using a background page and the popup page is using the background page for all sort of data processing. But in Firefox extension, I could not find any equivalent to Background Page.

Comment: Extensions built with the add-on SDK instead are much more like a node.js program - you get a main.js file that you can import modules into and use to do 'background tasks'. main.js can use modules like page-worker or page-mod to talk to html documents using asynchronous messages. For more, read the tutorialz: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials ...if you have a more specific question, eg the chrome extension does $x, how do I do it using the SDK, it would be easier to give you answers.

Comment: In the Chrome plugin we have Background.html and background.js. The Extension UI pages are using the background page for all sort of logic. Like 
window.Bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage().Bkg;
Bkg.account.showUserInfo();

What would be the equivalent design in Firefox Extension.Where should all the logics and scripts from background page fits in Firefox world. Did went though the firefox documentation but could not find anything as per the requirement.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking for without more info. Please update your question with a real example.